# How to make `ngOnChanges` work in `angular2`

Tags: angular

My child component as following:

```
'use strict';

import {Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ''
})
export class MyApp implements OnInit {

    @Input() options: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {
        console.log('changing', args);
    }

}
```

And Parent component as following:

```
'use strict';

import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyApp} from './MyApp';

@Component({
    selector: 'map-presentation',
    template: `<my-app [options]="opts"></my-app>
    <button (click)="updates($event)">UPDATES</button>
    `,
    directives: [MyApp]
})
export class MainApp {

    opts: any;

    constructor() {
        this.opts = {
            width: 500,
            height: 600
        };
    }

    updates() {
        console.log('before changes');
        this.opts = {
            name: 'nanfeng'
        };
    }

}
```

Each time while i clicked the "UPDATES" button, the `ngOnChanges` method never be called, but why?

I angular version i am using is "2.0.0-beta.8"

Comment: are you sure? because I think it gets fired when you click `update` button.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***[It's working](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Y29lSQT93Bp5mfkwr4s?p=preview)***
***app.ts***

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {child} from 'src/child';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <child-cmp [options]="opts"></child-cmp>
    <button (click)="updates($event)">UPDATES</button>
  `,
    directives: [child]
})
export class App {
   opts: any;

   constructor() {
      this.opts = {
          width: 500,
          height: 600
      };
   }

   updates() {
      console.log('after changes');
      this.opts = {
          name: 'micronyks'
      };
   }
};
```

***child.ts***

```
import {Input,Component,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `

    `
})
export class child   { 
    @Input() options: any;

    ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {
        console.log('onChange fired');
        console.log('changing', args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your plunker, I missed the `angular2-polyfills` part. Once i imported it, everything works

Comment: that's I said R u sure? great thing is that you actually fig it out.....btw great ! Enjoy...

Comment: @micronyks can you please help me to fix this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151925/ngonchanges-is-not-working-in-angular4

Answer (score 3):

Well it works with "input properties", this means with those passed in this format: @Input() myVariable: string;

I made it work normally when this input value is a string, number or boolean, but with objects I still do not now what's going on.

So, in the "AppComponent" template (the .html) can go something like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"> // name is a string property of the AppComponent
<app-test [myVal]="name"></app-test>
```

And the "test component" can look like this:

```
import {Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <div> TEST COMPONENT {{myVal}}</div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor() { }  
  ngOnChanges(changeRecord: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('It works!');
    /* changeRecord will have a property for each INPUT named the same
    as the input. These are added to changeRecord when the input
    gets a value */
    if(typeof changeRecord.myVal !== 'undefined){
          console.log('myVal = ', changeRecord.myVal.currentValue);
    }

  } 
  @Input() myVal: string;  
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: ngOnChanges lets you discover when the input value changes, and its previous value - see below for example.  ngOnChanges(changeRecord) {
    console.log('It works!'); If (typeof changeRecord.myVal !== undefined) console.log('myVal has changed :', changeRecord.myVal.currentValue);
  }

Comment: What is the point of changeRecord: SimpleChanges in the argument to ngOnChanges?  Most of the examples I have seen leave this out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't implemented interface OnChanges ..if you implement OnChanges interface then only ngOnChanges will be consider as lifecycle hook function and it will get call on input changes otherwise it will be consider as normal function